# Find paths of length = 4, starting by an adjacency matrix of a directed graph, considering only distinct edges?

Tags: graph, parallel-processing

Given an EREW-PRAM model, that allows me to use an arbitrary number of processors in parallel without them conflicting nor in read, nor in write access, I need to find the number of paths of length 4, considering that I have an input node-node adjacency matrix A representing a directed graph and that I need to exclude paths that don't use distinct edges (e.g.: (a,b),(b,a),(a,b),(b,a) is not a valid path).

I have a function that uses n^3 processors and calculates the matrix multiplication of two given matrices in time O(logn):

`mult-matrix(A, A, n) => B` --> gives me the paths of length 2.

`mult-matrix(B, B, n) => C` --> gives me the paths of length 4, but I think it considers paths that run across the same edges.

I tried subtracting 1 from elements of C that have a node u communicating with a node v in both directions, but I'm not sure it works.

How could I solve the problem considering that I just need to exclude some paths from the resulting matrix C?

Any working solution is appreciated, considering that the number of processors is constrained to n^3 and time must be O(logn) in the worst case. The exercises must be solved using a pseudo-pascal language, but given a working solution, I should be able to write the pseudocode by myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found a solution in https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=522270

Given an input matrix A, I am able to calculate the adjacency matrix for paths of length 2, 3 and 4 with the provided function.

- A2 is the adjacency matrix obtained by multiplying A*A and contains paths of length 2
- A3 is obtained by multiplying A2*A and contains paths of length 3
- A4 is obtained by multiplying A3*A and contains paths of length 4

In order to exclude the repeated edges, I have to compute the matrix C, obtained by doing **an element-wise subtraction** among the calculated matrices.

`C[i,j] = A4[i,j] - A3[i,j] - A2[i,j] - A[i,j]`

C contains the final result.

The following pseudocode solves the problem with an EREW-PRAM using O(n^3) processors and in time O(logn).

```
procedure paths_length_4(A, n) // Work = O(n^3 logn)
begin
    A2 := mult_matrix(A, A, n) // T=O(logn), P=O(n^3)
    A3 := mult_matrix(A2, A, n) // T=O(logn), P=O(n^3)
    A4 := mult_matrix(A3, A, n) // T=O(logn), P=O(n^3)
    for all i,j where 1 ≤ i ≤ n, 1 ≤ j ≤ n pardo // P=O(n^2)
        C[i,j] := A4[i,j] - A3[i,j] - A2[i,j] - A[i,j]
end
```